# Adding images via CSV with non standard file extensions

Tags: magento2, image-upload

I'm importing several thousand images from an existing system via a CSV upload referencing them in an Amazon S3 bucket.

I'm having difficulty with images which are perfectly valid images but do not have a .jpg file extension. Magento 2 seems to reject these with an error without actually attempting to get the image in question.

Some of these image file names were just miskeyed by whoever uploaded them as .jpe etc. In other cases I would like to run them through a file size standardiser like Imgx when uploading them as some are huge, but the query string to tell Imgx what size to make means that Magento rejects the URLs.

Is there any way to make Magento less fussy and actually download the image from the URL even if it does not end .jpg?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is very similar to a question I had previously - [Magento2 Product import (image filenames)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/171400/magento2-product-import-image-filenames)

If you specifically get "xxx is not a valid image format" error messages, then it's probably also worth looking at the `$allowImageTypes` array here: `Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Image`